# How to count the number of records in the model with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I want to count the number of records contained in the Suspenses property with a year of "2013" and a month of "1".

I get the error when I run the below code: "DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable types." I'm still new to ASP.Net MVC, not sure if this is the way to get my results. Hopefully I can learn from your comments. Your help will be appreciated.

```
 var suspenses = db.Suspenses.Include(s => s.User);
 int[] count = new int[12];

 for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
 {
     // to count number of account suspenses on every months
     suspenses = suspenses.Where(s => s.SuspenseDate.Year.Equals(year));
     suspenses = suspenses.Where(s => s.SuspenseDate.Month.Equals(i));
     count[i-1] = suspenses.Count();
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in a single line by grouping per month and counting the total like this :

```
var count = db.Suspenses.GroupBy(s => s.SuspenseDate.Month).Select(g=>g.Count());
```

Comment: Hi if I want to pass the count to another function what type of variable could it be?

Comment: .Select returns an IEnumerable but if you want a List you can just do a .ToList() behind the last ). Both the IEnumerable and the List will contain int types since g.Count() returns an int. Feel free to accepy my answer if it helped you out btw.

Comment: I add .ToArray() at last and finally success to display the result I wanted from your method.

Comment: Glad you got it working. You usually can convert all IEnumerable's to a list or an array. Not sure why the list didn't work out for you but hey, whatever floats your boat !

Comment: @WhoeverDownvoted : Feel free to add a reason for the downvote

Comment: Upvoted. Can't see a reason why someone would downvote this answer and net even provide a reasoning for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
int recordsInJanuary2013 = 
    db.Suspenses.Count(se => se.SuspenseDate.Month == 1 
                             && se.SuspenseDate.Year == 2013);
```

Comment: Thanks, mayabelle. It did helps me solved my problem.

Comment: His code is gonna execute at least 12 queries now ... too bad he didn't get the grouping concept as that would've been a perfect fit imho

Answer (score 0):

you can use sum in your order

```
var suspenses = db.Suspenses.sum(s => s.User).where(m => m.mounth == 12);
```